# Joining Multiple Tables With Left Join/ Outer Join

Tags: sql-server, join, multiple-join-rows

Hi I'm having trouble understanding `join` with multiple tables. I'm trying to get all data for each tables (Schedule,Forecast,Ideal,Actual). The query below would omit data from `vendor..ideal_labor` if the same data is not in the `edw..f_labor_dtl`. For example, if there is no data from `edw..f_labor_dtl` on day `'2019-02-07'`, the query would also omit from `vendor..ideal_labor` even if it has data on `'2019-02-07'`. This is easy to fix if I only have 2 tables joining eaching other (use `left/right join` or `full outer join`). Here with multiple tables, I'm using my 3 dimensions table as a left join (`SB_Finance.dbo.d_Job_Detail`, `edw..d_date`, `edw..d_store`). Meaning there would always be day `'2019-02-07'` in `edw..d_date`. How could when I `left join` on `edw..d_date`, it performed like an `inner join` on all the temp table?

```
with 
fcst as (
    select
        DOB as business_date,
        unit as store_id,
        JobCode as job_code,
        sum(Hours) as Hours
    from vendor..HotSchedulesOptimalsForecast
    group by dob,unit,JobCode
),
schd as (
    select
        DOB as business_date,
        unit as store_id,
        JobCode as job_code,
        sum(ScheduledMinutes/60.0) as Hours
    from vendor..HotSchedulesScheduled
    group by dob,unit,JobCode   
),
ideal as (
    select
        business_date,
        store_id,
        job_code,
        sum(ideal_hrs) as Hours
    from vendor..ideal_labor
    group by business_date,store_id,job_code    
),
act as (
    select
        business_date,
        store_id,
        job_code,
        sum(ttl_hrs) as Hours
    from edw..f_labor_dtl
    group by business_date,store_id,job_code    
)
select
    d.business_date,
    d.f_year,
    d.f_period,
    d.week_period,
    d.week_year,
    d.week_ending,
    s.store_id,
    s.store_desc,
    s.rpt_concept,
    s.region,
    j.job_code,
    j.job_name,
    j.Cat_OPKPI,
    sum(schd.Hours) as Schd_Hrs,
    sum(fcst.Hours) as Fcst_Hrs,
    sum(act.Hours) as Actl_Hrs,
    sum(ideal.Hours) as Ideal_Hrs
from SB_Finance.dbo.d_Job_Detail j
    left join fcst on j.job_code = fcst.job_code
    left join schd on j.job_code = schd.job_code
    left join ideal on j.job_code = ideal.job_code
    left join act act on j.job_code = act.job_code
    left join edw..d_date d on d.business_date = fcst.business_date and d.business_date = schd.business_date and d.business_date = ideal.business_date and d.business_date = act.business_date
    left join edw..d_store s on s.store_id = fcst.store_id and s.store_id = schd.store_id and s.store_id = ideal.store_id and s.store_id = act.store_id
where
    is_closed = 0
    and f_year = 2019
    and Cat_OPKPI in ('Service','Culinary','Support','Janitorial')
group by
    d.business_date,d.f_year,d.f_period,d.week_period,d.week_year,d.week_ending,s.store_id,s.store_desc,s.rpt_concept,s.region,j.job_code,j.job_name,j.Cat_OPKPI
```

Comment: Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what the inner join on is. Also: For code questions give a [mcve]. And part of that is a clear specification. Here you don't say what result you want in terms of inputs and you just give code that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after playing around with `join`. I'm using `cross join` on all dimensions table then use `left join` to connect the other data tables.

```
with 
fcst as (
    select
        DOB as business_date,
        unit as store_id,
        JobCode as job_code,
        sum(Hours) as Hours
    from vendor..HotSchedulesOptimalsForecast 
    group by dob,unit,JobCode
),
schd as (
    select
        DOB as business_date,
        unit as store_id,
        JobCode as job_code,
        sum(ScheduledMinutes/60.0) as Hours
    from vendor..HotSchedulesScheduled
    group by dob,unit,JobCode   
),
ideal as (
    select
        business_date,
        store_id,
        job_code,
        sum(ideal_hrs) as Hours
    from vendor..ideal_labor
    group by business_date,store_id,job_code    
),
act as (
    select
        business_date,
        store_id,
        job_code,
        sum(ttl_hrs) as Hours
    from edw..f_labor_dtl
    group by business_date,store_id,job_code    
), summary as (
select
    d.business_date,
    d.f_year,
    d.f_period,
    d.week_period,
    d.week_year,
    d.week_ending,
    s.store_id,
    s.store_desc,
    s.rpt_concept,
    s.region,
    j.job_code,
    j.job_name,
    j.Cat_OPKPI,
    isnull(sum(schd.Hours),0) as Schd_Hrs,
    isnull(sum(fcst.Hours),0) as Fcst_Hrs,
    isnull(sum(act.Hours),0) as Actl_Hrs,
    isnull(sum(ideal.Hours),0) as Ideal_Hrs
from SB_Finance.dbo.d_Job_Detail j
    cross join edw..d_date d
    cross join edw..d_store s
    left join fcst on j.job_code = fcst.job_code and d.business_date = fcst.business_date and s.store_id = fcst.store_id
    left join schd on j.job_code = schd.job_code and d.business_date = schd.business_date and s.store_id = schd.store_id
    left join ideal on j.job_code = ideal.job_code and d.business_date = ideal.business_date and s.store_id = ideal.store_id
    left join act on j.job_code = act.job_code and d.business_date = act.business_date and s.store_id = act.store_id

where
    is_closed = 0
    and d.f_year = 2019
    and Cat_OPKPI in ('Service','Culinary','Support','Janitorial')
group by
    d.business_date,d.f_year,d.f_period,d.week_period,d.week_year,d.week_ending,s.store_id,s.store_desc,s.rpt_concept,s.region,j.job_code,j.job_name,j.Cat_OPKPI
```